# Como puedo importar datos de excel a mysql sin que se repitan registros y que edite los campos que cambiaron

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy importando datos de un archivo *excel* a *mysql* con ***PHPexcel***. Todo funciona correctamente, **evito que los datos se dupliquen** con *UQ* en la llave primaria. **Pero quiero que edite los campos que han cambiado en los registros**, es decir, La tabla es de empleados. Entonces de pronto cambia el turno o el departamento en el que están, y no quiero que se actualice el registro completo, solo que cambie esos campos.

Pienso que la solución debería hacerla a nivel base de datos, pero no se como. Que debo hacer?

Les comparto el codigo por si es de utilidad. Esto es de la importación de la ***BD***:

```
<?php
include "database.php";
include "class.upload.php";
if(isset($_FILES["name"])){
$up = new Upload($_FILES["name"]);
if($up->uploaded){
    $up->Process("./uploads/"); 
    if($up->processed){
        /// leer el archivo excel
        require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        $archivo = "uploads/".$up->file_dst_name;
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 

            $x_idEmpleados = $sheet->getCell("A".$row)->getValue();
            $x_nombre = $sheet->getCell("C".$row)->getValue();
            $x_departamento = $sheet->getCell("E".$row)->getValue();
            $x_codigo = $sheet->getCell("I".$row)->getValue();
            $x_turno = $sheet->getCell("H".$row)->getValue();

            $sql = "insert into empleados (idEmpleados, nombre, departamento, codigo, turno, 
                                            fechaAlta) value ";

            $sql .= " (\"$x_idEmpleados\",\"$x_nombre\",\"$x_departamento\",\"$x_codigo\",\"$x_turno\",
                        NOW())";

           $con->query($sql);
        }
    unlink($archivo);
    }   

}
    }
    echo "<script>
    window.location = './index.php';
    </script>
    ";
    ?>
```

Esto sería de la visualización de los datos:

```
if( $datos -> num_rows > 0):?>
<br>
<h3>Datos</h3>
<p>Resultados <?php echo $datos->num_rows; ?></p>
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="bg-dark text-white text-center">Empleado</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-white text-center">Nombre</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-white text-center">Departamento</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-white text-center">Codigo</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-white text-center">Turno</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-white text-center">Alta en Sistema</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-white text-center">Historial Clinico</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <?php while($d= $datos->fetch_object()):?> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="bg-secondary text-white"><?php echo $d->idEmpleados; ?></td>
    <td style="background-color:rgba( 233, 130, 26, 0.5 )"><?php echo $d->nombre; ?></td>
    <td style="background-color:rgba( 233, 130, 26, 0.8 )"><?php echo $d->departamento; ?></td>
    <td style="background-color:rgba( 233, 130, 26, 0.5 )"><?php echo $d->codigo; ?></td>
    <td style="background-color:rgba( 233, 130, 26, 0.8 )"><?php echo $d->turno; ?></td>
    <td style="background-color:rgba( 233, 130, 26, 0.5 )"><?php echo $d->fechaAlta; ?></td>
    <td><a href='editar.php?id=".$row[0]."'></a>Ver</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<?php else:?>
<h3>No hay Datos</h3>
```

Les agradezco por su tiempo de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Alon G,
Se bien lo he comprendido tu quieres actualizar algunos campos de los registros.
Les dejo un ejemplo para que haga los cambios e pruebe en su código.

```
  // hacer una busqueda en la base antes de añadir un nuevo registro
    // Debes elegir los campos de la llave primaria para busqueda
  $result = mysql_query("select * from empleados where idEmpleados = '$x_idEmpleados' and nombre = '$x_nombre' and departamento = '$x_departamento' and codigo = '$x_codigo' and turno = '$x_turno' ");
  $lineas = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $info = mysql_fetch_object($result);

    if ($lineas == 0){ // no fue encontrado un registro , insertar nuevo registro
         $sql = "insert into empleados (idEmpleados, nombre, departamento, codigo, turno, 
                                    fechaAlta) value ";

       $sql .= " (\"$x_idEmpleados\",\"$x_nombre\",\"$x_departamento\",\"$x_codigo\",\"$x_turno\",  NOW())";            

  $con->query($sql);
  }

    if ($lineas > 0){ // Fue encontrado un registro, cambiar los campos
                      // llenar los campos que deben ser cambiados
                                        // quitar los que no seran afectados
         $sql = "update empleados 
         set (idEmpleados='', nombre='', departamento='', codigo='', turno='', fechaAlta = ''
         where idEmpleados='' and ??");// se hubier mas de un campo de la llave primaria

         // haga los cambios necesarios en esa parte
     mysql_query($sql,$con)or die("Hubo un erro en la actualizacion SQL:".mysql_error());
       con->query($sql);         
 }
```

Saludos.